# Enumerate ItemsControl.Items as UIElements

Tags: silverlight, itemscontrol, uielement

I have a list of hyperlinks that are displayed through an `ItemsControl`, something like this:

```
 <ItemsControl x:Name="SubMenu" Visibility="Collapsed">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Name}"
                                 NavigateUri="{Binding Url}"
                                 TargetName="ContentFrame"
                                 Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}"
                                 />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource LinksStackPanelStyle}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    </ItemsControl>
```

what I need to do is enumerate the actual hyperlinks in the submenu, something like this:

```
    foreach (UIElement child in SubMenu.Items) // this does not work!
    {
        HyperlinkButton hb = child as HyperlinkButton;
        if (hb != null && hb.NavigateUri != null)
        {
            if (hb.NavigateUri.ToString().Equals(e.Uri.ToString()))
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "ActiveLink", true);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "InactiveLink", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I can´t seem to find a way to enumerate the actual UI elements in the ItemsCollection.Items.

Anyone know how to do this or a possible workaround?

I can mention that what I´m trying to do is build a menu and submenu that display the hyperlinks clicked as a sort of breadcrumb.

**UPDATE:**
The best thing would be if I could get to that stackpanel somehow because this code seems to work:

```
    foreach (UIElement child in LinksStackPanel.Children)
    {
        HyperlinkButton hb = child as HyperlinkButton;
        if (hb != null && hb.NavigateUri != null)
        {
            if (hb.NavigateUri.ToString().Equals(e.Uri.ToString()))
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "ActiveLink", true);
            }
            else
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "InactiveLink", true);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution looks like this:

```
foreach (var item in SubMenu.Items)
{
    var hb = SubMenu.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item).FindVisualChild<HyperlinkButton>();

    if (hb.NavigateUri.ToString().Equals(e.Uri.ToString()))
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "ActiveLink", true);
    }
    else
    {
        VisualStateManager.GoToState(hb, "InactiveLink", true);
    }
}
```

The extension method FindVisualChild:

```
public static T FindVisualChild<T>(this DependencyObject instance) where T : DependencyObject
{
    T control = default(T);

    if (instance != null)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(instance); i++)
        {
            if ((control = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(instance, i) as T) != null)
            {
                break;
            }

            control = FindVisualChild<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(instance, i));
        }
    }

    return control;

}
```

Comment: This deserves more up-votes. Only place on the net I found the solution after searching for a day.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.containerfromitem(VS.95).aspx) method

```
foreach (var item in SubMenu.Items)
{ 
    var child = SubMenu.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
    HyperlinkButton hb = child as HyperlinkButton; 
    // use hb
}
```

Comment: +1 You were just about right and helped me along the way. I have solved it a little bit differently. See my own answer to the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

FindVisualChild from Johan Leino answer has bug: traversing of lower levels in control hierarchy does not have any effect because he don't check result of recursive call.

That is fixed version.

```
public static T FindVisualChild<T>(this DependencyObject instance) where T : DependencyObject
{
    T control = default(T);

    if (instance != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(instance); i++)
        {
            if ((control = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(instance, i) as T) != null)
            {
                break;
            }

            if ((control = FindVisualChild<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(instance, i))) != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return control;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach (UIElement child in SubMenu.Items.OfType<UIElement>())
```

This is using the [`Enumerable.OfType<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method that filters the collection down to only those items that are of the specified type.

Comment: No, sorry that does not work. It seems that elements in Items are not the actual UI elements. Items contains typeof(MenuItem) which is the business object that I use to bind to the collection.